# Remove everything before first timestamp in webvtt file - JS

Tags: javascript, regex, webvtt, vtt

I try to remove everything before first timestamp in `.vtt` file.

I made something `.replace(/(.*)\s+1/gmi, '')` but it select "1" as well. My expecting is to select everything except "1" which should be a first line in file.

```
WEBVTT

1
00:00:00.080 --> 00:00:05.930
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 

2
00:00:05.930 --> 00:00:07.430
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 

3
00:00:07.430 --> 00:00:13.130
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

```
1
00:00:00.080 --> 00:00:05.930
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 

2
00:00:05.930 --> 00:00:07.430
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 

3
00:00:07.430 --> 00:00:13.130
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

Comment: Not to include 1 you can use lookahead. In case of your regex: `(.*)\s+(?=1)`

Comment: I had to modify it a little for exclude numbers like 10, 11, 12... `(.*)\s+(?=1$)`. Anyway it helps me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use

```
.replace(/^.*\s+(?=^1$)/m, '')
```

I removed `g`lobal flag because this expression must remove from start of string only. `m` is preserved, it makes both anchors be applied at start and end of a line.
Capturing parentheses are not necessary.

`(?=^1$)` ensures the match comes before a line with a single `1` on it.

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/X5e1Td/1).